# Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)=F(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, random-variables, independence

> Let be $X_n, Y_n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, random variables and $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that for $x\in\mathbb{R}$
> $$
> \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(X_n\leq x)=F(x), ~\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon)=0, ~\epsilon>0.
> $$
>
> Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)=F(x).$

**My approach:**

We choose an arbitrary $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. We know that $P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)=P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x)+P(|Y_n|< \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x)$. Further,

$\begin{align*}
&P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x)\leq P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon)\\
&\implies 0\leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x) \leq\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon)=0\\
&\implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x) =0.
\end{align*}$

Now we find an upper bound of $P(|Y_n|< \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x)$:

\begin{align*}
&P(|Y_n|< \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x)\leq P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon,~X_n\leq x-Y_n)\leq P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon,~X_n\leq x+\epsilon)\\
&\implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|Y_n|< \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x) \leq\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|Y_n|< \epsilon,~X_n\leq x+\epsilon)\\
&\leq\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} P(X_n\leq x+\epsilon)=F(x+\epsilon).
\end{align*}

Next, we find a lower bound of $P(|Y_n|< \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x)$:

\begin{align*}
&P(|Y_n|< \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x)= P(|Y_n|< \epsilon,~ X_n\leq x-Y_n)\\
&\geq (|Y_n|< \epsilon,~ X_n\leq x-\epsilon)=1-P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon\cup X_n> x-\epsilon)\\
&\geq 1-P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon)-P(X_n> x-\epsilon) =P(X_n\leq x-\epsilon)-P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon)\\
&\implies \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon,~ X_n+Y_n\leq x) \geq\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(X_n\leq x-\epsilon)-\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(|Y_n|\geq \epsilon)\\
&=F(x-\epsilon)-0.
\end{align*}
Finally,
$\begin{align*}
& F(x-\epsilon)\leq\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)\leq F(x+\epsilon).
\end{align*}$
Note that $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary and $F$ is continuous. So we can shrink the $\epsilon$ and get $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}P(X_n+Y_n\leq x)=F(x)$.

Is this correct? Maybe there are other approaches? Any feedback is welcome!

Comment: This is just an easier version on [Slutky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402536/slutskys-theorem-jun-shaos-mathematical-statistics) a reference for a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof looks good. I would proceed in the exact same way, just using stricter definitions of the limit.

Let $\delta > 0$ be arbitrary. We show that there exists $N_\delta$ such that $|P (X_n + Y_n \le x) - F (x)| < \delta$ for each $n > N_\delta$.

---

First, since $F$ is continuous, for any $\delta_1 > 0$, there exists $\varepsilon' > 0$ such that $|x' - x| < \varepsilon' \implies |F (x') - F (x)| < \delta_1$. In particular, letting $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon'$, this implies that

$$\color{orange}{|F (x + \varepsilon) - F (x)| < \delta_1}$$

as well as that

$$\color{orange}{|F (x - \varepsilon) - F (x)| < \delta_1}$$

---

Now we note (as you have) that

$$\color{red}{P (X_n + Y_n \le x) = P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| \ge \varepsilon) + P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| < \varepsilon)}$$

---

We start by analyzing the first term, which we expect to be small:

$$P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| \ge \varepsilon) \le P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon)$$

Since we are given that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon) = 0$, then the above guarantees, for any $\delta_2 > 0$, that there exists some $N_2$ such that $|P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon)| < \delta_2$ for each $n > N_2$. By triangle inequality, we have that

$$\color{blue}{|P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| \ge \varepsilon)| < \delta_2}$$

for each $n > N_2$.

---

Now let's look at the second term, which we expect to be close to $F (x)$. We have the inequalities

$$P (X_n \le x - \varepsilon) - P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon) \le P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| < \varepsilon) \le P (X_n \le x + \varepsilon)$$

for each $n$. By hypothesis, $\lim_{n \to \infty} P (X_n \le x - \varepsilon) = F (x - \varepsilon)$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon) = 0$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} P (X_n \le x + \varepsilon) = F (x + \varepsilon)$. So, given any $\delta_3, \delta_4 > 0$, there exist $N_3, N_4$ such that

$$\begin{cases}
|P (X_n \le x - \varepsilon) - F (x - \varepsilon)| < \delta_3 \\
|P (X_n \le x + \varepsilon) - F (x + \varepsilon)| < \delta_4
\end{cases}$$

for each $n > N_3, n > N_4$, respectively. Combining with the result of the previous section (in blue), we find

$$|(P (X_n \le x - \varepsilon) - P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon)) - F (x - \varepsilon)| < \delta_2 + \delta_3$$

for each $n > \max \{ N_2, N_3 \}$. Combining with the first result through triangle inequality (in orange), we see that

$$\begin{cases}
|(P (X_n \le x - \varepsilon) - P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon)) - F (x)| < \delta_1 + \delta_2 + \delta_3 \\
|P (X_n \le x + \varepsilon) - F (x)| < \delta_1 + \delta_4
\end{cases}$$

both hold for each $n > \max \{ N_2, N_3, N_4 \}$. Now, due to the "sandwiching" inequalities listed at the top of this part, for $\delta' = \max \{ \delta_1 + \delta_2 + \delta_3, \delta_1 + \delta_4 \}$, we have that

$$\color{purple}{|P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| < \varepsilon) - F (x)| < \delta'}$$

for each $n > \max \{ N_2, N_3, N_4 \}$. If this last step is not clear, take a few cases of where $F (x)$ is located with respect to the interval $[P (X_n \le x - \varepsilon) - P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon), P (X_n \le x + \varepsilon)]$.

---

Finally, combining the previous results (red, blue, purple), we conclude that

$$|(P (X_n + Y_n \le x)) - F (x)| < \delta' + \delta_2$$

for each $n > \max \{ N_2, N_3, N_4 \}$. Choosing, say, $\delta_1 = \delta_2 = \delta_3 = \delta_4 = \frac{1}{4} \delta$ completes the proof (note that for this choice, $\delta' = \frac{3}{4} \delta$).

Comment: I am not sure if it is a typo. I think instead of $$P (X_n \le x \color {red}{+} \varepsilon) - P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon) \le P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| < \varepsilon) \le P (X_n \le x + \varepsilon)$$ it should be $$ P (X_n \le x - \varepsilon) - P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon) \le P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| < \varepsilon) \le P (X_n \le x + \varepsilon).$$

Comment: How do you justify your statement: "Equivalently, $$|P (X_n \le x - Y_n, |Y_n| < \varepsilon) - P (X_n \le x + \varepsilon)| \le P (|Y_n| \ge \varepsilon)".$$

Comment: You are correct; that is a typo. But the proof remains similar. I'll fix it.